# javascript not working in OPERA

Tags: javascript, opera

This javascript works in Firefox, IE, Chrome but Not in Opera. How to make it cross browser compatible? 
I need script to detect click on iframe.

```
<script>
var isOverIFrame = false;
function processMouseOut() {
isOverIFrame = false;
top.focus();
}
function processMouseOver() { isOverIFrame = true; }
function processIFrameClick() {
if(isOverIFrame) {
//was clicked
}
}

function init() {
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
    element[i].onmouseover = processMouseOver;
    element[i].onmouseout = processMouseOut;
}
if (typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
    top.attachEvent('onblur', processIFrameClick);
}
else if (typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
    top.addEventListener('blur', processIFrameClick, false);
}
}
</script>

<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>

<script>init();</script>
```

Comment: Which version of opera are you using? Is there any opera documentation you have researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `script` tags:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an odd thing to do - your JavaScript should not be able to detect what the user does in an IFRAME from a different domain. The "blur" event is not a reliable indicator that the user clicked in the IFRAME (what if she just switched to another window?).

In short: what you're trying to do is against the architecture of web scripting, for good reasons that have to do with security and privacy, hence you can not do it reliably.